# How do get only first value from JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having `JSON Object` in ajax response [image: like that.]
I have to show these message on UI , for this I am using linke that .`msg.result.word_containing_more_than_avg_chars` It will works fine . But the problem is key is dynamic, in some case key`word_containing_more_than_avg_chars` becomes `title_containing_more_than_avg_Words` . SO how do handle all case in such that I can get `value` part only irrespective of `key` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the key using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method which returns an array of object property names.

```
msg.result[Object.keys(msg.result)[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>

<script>

testobj = {"a" : "123", "b" : "234"};
testArray = [];
for (key in testobj) {
    testArray.push(testobj[key]);
}
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = testArray[0];

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought that I would answer this in a more generic way.

I saw it a little less efficient than the answer that is already here, however I personally iterate through them using a for loop, because it seems that at least in Chrome there was not an appropriate method for keys on the Object.

[image: NoKeysMethodProof]

Answer (score 0):

Below code is more efficient,

```
Object.values(msg.result)[0];
```